# how to add a new calendar events in windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7, class, calendar, appointment

I guess appointment class for Windows Phone is read only class. Can any one suggest me on how to create a calender event in Windows Phone 7 application. Is there any API available for the same.

Thanks,
Harlborn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the [google calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) and the [Windows Live calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#calendar) have a rest API. You might be able to do something by calling these methods. I have never tried either of these, but they might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create or edit calendar items in windows phone 7